# Ordered abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Consider the following axioms:

1) $\ x+(y+z)=(x+y)+z$ ;   $\forall x \forall y \forall z$

2) $\ x+0=x$           ;     $\forall x$

3) $\forall x$ $ \exists y$ such that $\ x+y=0$

4) $ \ x+y=y+x$  ; $\forall x \forall y$

5) $ \ x\nless x$  ;$\forall x$

6) $ \ x< y \textrm{ and } y< z \textrm{ implies } x<z$    ;$\forall x \forall y\forall z$

7) $\ x<y \textrm{ or } x=y \textrm{ or } y<x$              ;$\forall x\forall y $

8) $x<y \textrm{ implies } x+z<y+z$                        ;$\forall x\forall y\forall z$

Can 8) be deduced from 1),...,7) axioms? If yes, can you sketch a proof? I've done this question to an authomatic proover tool (using 1) to 7) as axioms and 8) as conjecture), which has been working hard from Sunday and gave me no answer so far. But due to the semidecidability of first order logic, I can't deduce from horrible noises coming from hard disk that the conjecture is false. Can you help?

Comment: Looking at the two answers so far, one cannot undersell how important is the completeness theorem in mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no.  Here's a simple counterexample.  Consider the group $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, consisting of the elements $0,1,2$.  They may be ordered however you like, e.g. $0<1<2$ or $2<0<1$.  Those total orderings are all consistent with (1)-(7), but not with (8).  You need (8) to prove that this group cannot be totally ordered.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the abelian group $\mathbb Z$ and define $$x\prec y\iff |3x+1|<|3y+1|$$